# HPLIP 3.12.4 plugin installer failing to install in LUBUNTU

Tags: 12.04, lubuntu, hplip

HPLIP 3.12.4 plugin installer fails with:
QGtkStyle was unable to detect the current GTK+ theme.

How can I make this work in Lubuntu to get my printer working?
Plugin installer can be found here:
http://www.openprinting.org/download/printdriver/auxfiles/HP/plugins/

I used: hplip-3.12.4-plugin.run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a forum thread with this exact same error over at the [Arch forums](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3acd8QVBQyPlIJ%3ahttps://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=775685%20&cd=1&hl=sv&ct=clnk&gl=se), but I can't help but wonder, if the only reason this plugin refuses to run is because of a GTK theme warning, couldn't you just run it from a non-GUI prompt? That is, press ctrl+alt+F1, login and then run it. Could be worth a shot.

Comment: that what I was doing. I ran sudo and the command.